# Multiple imports in one row

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to optimize my import. Is there any way to import type and default in one row using Flow?

```
import { default as ListIcon } from './List';
import type { Props as ListProps } from './List';

import { default as GridIcon } from './Grid';
import type { Props as GridProps } from './Grid';
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can [Import multiple exports from module as follows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import { default as ListIcon, Props as ListProps } from './List';
```

Comment: if I do so, I will receive warning like 'Cannot import the type Props as a value. Use import type instead'

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn yes, you cannot use object destructuring on types, and this is why : https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6590#issuecomment-404137654
Would the import * suit your needs ?

Comment: @Logar not quite.. I need something like this `import type { Props as ListProps }, Listicon from './List';`